Negating a Quantified Boolean Formula (QBF)
I'm reading about quantified boolean formulas. One sentence mentions:

You should also verify that the negation of the formula $Q_1x_1\cdot\cdot\cdot Q_nx_n \phi(x_1, ..., x_n)$ is the same as $Q^{\prime}_1x_1\cdot\cdot\cdot Q_n^{\prime}x_n \neg\phi(x_1, ..., x_n)$, where $Q^{\prime}_i$ is $\exists$ if $Q_i$ is $\forall$ and vice-versa.

I know the identity $\neg\forall\phi(x) = \exists x\neg\phi(x)$. Also, it seems like $\neg$ is, in some cases, distributive.
How do I use those two things to verify that statement?

You're right in that the identity you need is essentially $\neg \forall X. \phi = \exists X. \neg \phi$ and (symmetrically) $\neg \exists X. \phi = \forall X. \neg \phi$.
One can proceed via proof by induction.
Base case: It is obvious that $\neg Q_1 x_1. \phi(x_1)= Q_1' x_1. \neg \phi(x_1)$ via the properties above.
Inductive case: Assume the statement is true for $n-1$, i.e. $\neg(Q_1 x_1. Q_2 x_2., ..., Q_{n-1} x_{n-1}. \phi(x_1,...,x_{n-1})) = Q'_1 x_1... Q'_{n-1} x_{n-1}. \neg\phi(x_1,...,x_{n-1})$. Then
$$ 
Q_1 x_1,..., Q_n x_n. \phi_n (x_1,...,x_n)= Q_1x_1,...,Q_{n-1}x_{n-1} (Q_n x_n.\phi(x_1,...,x_n)) \\
= Q'_1 x_1...Q'_{n-1}x_{n-1}.\neg(Q_nx_n.\phi(x_1,...,x_n)) \text{ by ind.hyp.} \\
= Q'_1 x_1,...,Q'_nx_n.\neg\phi(x_1,...,x_n)\text{ by negation properties above.}
$$

The reasoning is OK, however you are missing negations before the original quantifiers: $\lnot Q \phi = Q' \lnot \phi$. Also, the base case can even be where $n=0$, so without quantifiers. (The inductive case also works for $n=1$.)

@HendrikJan I corrected the typo in the base case. Thanks for pointing it out.

Sorry that I was not really explicit, but also the inductive case at the start needs a negation before the sequence of original quantifiers.
